# PHP ending code blocks

Tags: php, asp-classic

first of all my english is not so good but it will be enogh. So i recently use php language and before then i used classic asp.

I dont know how to define myself but i try it

In asp: when i write this codes

```
<div class="deneme1"></div>
<%
response.write("Deneme<br>")
%>
<div class="deneme2"></div>
```

It will return like this (in browser source code view)

```
<div class="deneme1"></div>
Deneme<br>
<div class="deneme2"></div>
```

U see asp desn't delete the line character after closing asp block.

But in the php, when i write like this

```
<div class="deneme1"></div>
<?php
echo("Deneme<br>");
?>
<div class="deneme2"></div>
```

it will return this

```
<div class="deneme1"></div>
Deneme<br><div class="deneme2"></div>
```

I know it will not necessary to u guys but it bothering to me :/

Comment: Try `echo("Deneme<br>\n");`

Comment: Why would you want this? Less lines = Smaller file size = faster loading time

Comment: i do try that and PHP_EOL, but thats not the answer i looking for. Is there any way to solve it in php.ini or other way? (changing like setting or something)

Comment: @ZeeTee I said before, its bothering to me my frined.

Answer (score 1):

You could place a space after the closing tag like so:

```
<div class="deneme1"></div>
<?php
echo("Deneme<br>");
?> <----- space here 
<div class="deneme2"></div>
```